# leak at status parser method in libxml

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I had a problem with the LibXMLParser when I ran it in the instruments. the following is my code that I used.

```
- (id)statusParser
{
    return [[[self class] alloc] init];
}
```

The memory is leaking at return method.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **`autorelease`**?

```
 - (id)statusParser
{
    return [[[[self class] alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```